# Apt-get not working after removing libusb

Tags: apt

I did not how to put up the title of the question, so sorry.

Accidentally, I did `sudo apt-get remove libusb` instead of `sudo apt-get remove libusb-dev`.

And now nothing is working. How can I revert this?

Comment: OK. Please run `sudo apt-get install libusb` and post here the exact output of this command. It seems strange to me that apt-get should be influenced by libusb, as libusb is a userspace USB programming library.

Comment: sudo: apt-get: command not found.
my mistake has removed everything , software centre is gone , nautilus is gone and so more..

Comment: Do you have `Synaptic Package Manager` installed?

Comment: No , I dont.
  :(

Comment: Can you post the output for `ls -l /usr/bin/apt-get`?

Comment: @BiggJJ  @ January. well i got from where to install _apt_ ,[link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apt).
but as you can see there are many dependencies.
is there a way that I dont have to download each one of them and then dpkg.
I mean , Is it possible to state it in a command line to retrieve and dpkg all dependencies simultaneously?

Comment: Use the links at the bottom of the page to download the package for your architecture. This should include all the depends and suggests. As for the installing, I maybe wrong, But I think doing the install will install all the packages.

Comment: @Ubuntu_beginner No Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the links at the bottom of [Package: apt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apt)  to download the package for your architecture.

This should include all the depends and suggests. As for the installation, doing the install will install all the packages