# No unity shell , no unity panel and no dual monitors

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, lightdm, unity-2d, kdm

I did something terrible this morning [you can see here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313742/apt-get-not-working-after-removing-libusb/313779?noredirect=1#313779)

Now that problem was fixed , apt was working fine and so was the update manager .

after installing all updates , I rebooted.

And I could not log in. The login page will like *refresh* after I enter my password , every time.
Then I installed **KDM** in place of **LIGHTDM** , and now I have no Unity shell , no panel , and the display settings gives an error

***GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XRANDR_2' on object at path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/XRANDR***

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if I can revert back to **lightdm**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the instructions to fix this:

1. Open the Startup Applications program from your Dash.
2. Click Add.
3. Name the item Unity Shell.
4. Type the command you use to start Unity in the Command option.
5. Click Add.
6. Click Close.
7. Restart your computer and Unity should start up.

Comment: Well I tried and found out that its installed. I dont have a problem with **KDM** ,but i have to manually run unity every time I log in and of course i cant use dual monitor.

Comment: I updated the instructions to match your problem.

Comment: thanx. it worked. :)